# how to run ldap in URL

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I would like to connect windows server 2012 via browser by using ldap://ip:389 , but when I run this URL , it pops "Launch application , windows contacts , choose an application..." , I am administrator but can not do that , would advise how to do it to let me use this method "ldap://ip:389" to connect the LDAP ? thanks

Comment: use any LDAP browser like ldp

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all browsers) don't speak the LDAP protocol. I don't know exactly what you're expecting the browser to display, but it won't do it.